# Making SVG Images Clickable To Go To Link

Tags: svg

Im pretty new to SVG images and paths, but I've got this image which has a changing gradient, that i want to provide a link to some web address (say http://www.google.com).

I am not sure how to create a link to a page.

This is the code for the SVG:

```
<svg>
        <defs>
            <linearGradient id="colorGradient">
                <stop offset="0%" stop-color="green" stop-opacity=".5">
                <animate attributeName="stop-color" values="green;blue;red;red;black;red;red;purple;green" dur="18s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
                </stop>
                <stop offset="0.0536421" stop-color="green" stop-opacity=".5">
                    <animate attributeName="stop-color" values="green;orange;purple;purple;black;purple;purple;blue;green" dur="18s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
                    <animate attributeName="offset" values=".95;.80;.60;.40;.20;0;.20;.40;.60;.80;.95" dur="18s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
                </stop>
            </linearGradient>
        </defs> 
    <g fill="url(#colorGradient)">
        <path xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" d="M19 6h5v-6h-5c-3.86 0-7 3.14-7 7v3h-4v6h4v16h6v-16h5l1-6h-6v-3c0-0.542 0.458-1 1-1z"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Links are just `<a>` tags wrapped around drawing objects.

```html
<svg>
        <defs>
            <linearGradient id="colorGradient">
                <stop offset="0%" stop-color="green" stop-opacity=".5">
                <animate attributeName="stop-color" values="green;blue;red;red;black;red;red;purple;green" dur="18s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
                </stop>
                <stop offset="0.0536421" stop-color="green" stop-opacity=".5">
                    <animate attributeName="stop-color" values="green;orange;purple;purple;black;purple;purple;blue;green" dur="18s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
                    <animate attributeName="offset" values=".95;.80;.60;.40;.20;0;.20;.40;.60;.80;.95" dur="18s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
                </stop>
            </linearGradient>
        </defs>
    <a xlink:href="www.google.com">
    <g fill="url(#colorGradient)">
        <path xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" d="M19 6h5v-6h-5c-3.86 0-7 3.14-7 7v3h-4v6h4v16h6v-16h5l1-6h-6v-3c0-0.542 0.458-1 1-1z"/>
    </g>
    </a>
</svg>
```

Comment: Awesome thanks. Didnt realise it was that easy, was looking for ages and nowhere specified it like that